# Laravel - how to add global information like \Auth::user()

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have some custom middleware where I do my own authentication on some routes, and I want that middleware to make certain pieces of information available to the controllers, via an interface kind of like how you can do `\Auth::user();` to get the user from anywhere.

What I've been doing it is adding it onto the `$request` object, but I suspect that's not best practice.

Comment: You could create a custom [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/facades) or [helper](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) so you'll have the info you want available wherever you want.

Comment: @KennyHorna thank you, will look into that asap

Answer (score 0):

Request class's $attributes property is perfect for that purpose.

```
/**
 * Custom parameters.
 *
 * @var ParameterBag
 */
public $attributes;
```